# React router + Vercel serverless app deployment

Tags: reactjs, deployment, react-router, vercel

in my dev my react router routes work perfectly , in production its not working at all
i tried in my .vercel project.json that in the root : {
"orgId": "VJBjZWx1rKkUp7DiNM6Eza19",
"projectId": "prj_AGMAWLTxh5TDSGWAfPam41AWptE0",
"rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/" }]
}

Comment: when i try to find a route in production its gives me 404: NOT_FOUND
Code: NOT_FOUND
ID: cdg...